# DGraph-js, how to run a schema query?

Tags: node.js, dgraph

I'm new to Dgraph and am bashing my head against a simple issue with dgraph-js. I've even pored through the github sourcecode but I've clearly missed what I'm looking for.

Within the dgraph-ratel interface I can run this query:

```
schema(pred: [name]) {
  type
  index
}
```

or even just

```
schema {}
```

to get schema information about the database. But within dgraph-js if I use the query transaction, it works fine for normal queries:

```
const res = await this.connection.newTxn().query(`query {
    getData(func: regexp(name, /.*mic+.*/i)) {
        name
    }
}`);
const data = res.getJson();
```

but running the following:

```
const res = await this.connection.newTxn().query(`schema {}`);
const data = res.getJson();
```

returns an empty object. I suspect that I shouldn't be using newTxn().query() but something else. Should it be a new dGraph.Operation()? Or maybe something else? Where can I see all the functions available to me? The readme on the dgraph-js (https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph-js) only provides so much information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
res.getSchemaList();
```

As you can find in https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph-js/blob/18fa97c66bf9a2c897bf77ded119c1d1cb79333e/generated/api_pb.d.ts#L46

Cheers.